# Mirror API - Accessing the actual speech binary rather than translated text

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is it possible to access the actual speech recording, rather than the transcoded speech text from Mirror API

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently available in the Mirror API.

If this is something you need, file an [enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) and include a description of what you plan to use it for.